# JQuery UI: ui.draggable is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui

Firebug throw error on last line. I guess it's a syntax problem? I am basically copying from this [tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/), can't see why it doesn't work.

```
TypeError: ui.draggable is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
ui.draggable({ containment: 'body'});
```

code:

```
    function handleDropbox(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable);  // put this first!!!
        ui.draggable.addClass( 'selected' );
        $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
        ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'center center', at: 'center center' } );
        ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
        ui.draggable({ containment: 'parent'});
    }
```

Comment: have you added jquery.js and jquery-ui.js ? if added can you check whether it is loaded

Comment: Try adding "(JQuery);" after });

Comment: If `ui` is not a jQuery object you will need to use `$(ui)`. So it depends on how you pass the `ui` parameter to `handleDropbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the `ui.draggable` is indeed not a function here; it's a jQuery object (which has `draggable` widget applied). Perhaps you're looking for this:

```
ui.draggable.draggable('option', {containment: 'body'});
```

Actually, it might make sense to combine this statement with the previous one:

```
ui.draggable.draggable('option', {revert: false, containment: 'body'});
```

... as you can pass more than one option in a form of object.

Comment: So `ui.draggable` is the object being dragged, while `ui.draggable.draggable()` is the function which takes many parameters?

Comment: Yes, it's a generic helper method used to adjust/setup widget itself. It's a common pattern in jQuery UI.

Comment: Why jquery's syntax is so confusing? Is is just me or for many people? I come from a ObjC background. Any advice?

Comment: You'll get used to it, believe me. ) Actually, they got better in the recent revision; more consistent in their naming, etc. I suggest updating to the fresh version (1.10) if your project is fresh too.